# Participant non-compliance: How to include data in analysis

Tags: anova

I conducted a study in which participants were to do one of three treatment options and then write a test. The intention was to separate the participants based on the option they selected and using a one-way ANOVA, analyze whether these groups were statistically different from one another by comparing test grades.

The number of participants that did one of three treatment options were as follows:

- Option 1, n = 27
- Option 2, n = 98
- Option 3, n = 69

The issue I ran into is that several participants misread the instructions and did all three options, or some combination of two of the three options.

The number of participants that did more than one treatment option:

- Options 1, 2 and 3, n = 13
- Options 1 and 2, n = 17
- Options 1 and 3, n = 10
- Options 2 and 3, n = 20

Is there a way to use the test data from this group of people (those that did more than one treatment option) in the statistical analysis? For example, can I somehow compare these groups’ test grades to those of the single option groups? Or should they be excluded from the analysis (i.e. per-protocol analysis)?

I looked into complier-average causal effect (CACE) analysis, however in this case I don’t have a control group and there’s no way to determine which of the treatment options (for those that did more than one) had the effect, if any, on the test grade.

Any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

-Carmen

Comment: Is it possible that the instructions were misread as a result of your treatments?  If so, this would be important information to include in your questions as it will surely affect the answers you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 3 dummy variables X1, X2, X3 to indicate which treatment option the participant took part in. For example, if the one took all of the three options, then X1=1, X2=1, X3=1. Then fit the model with X1, X2, X3 and their interactioins as covariates.

Comment: Since this is a reverse compliance problem where some subjects provided too much data rather than the usual case of too little, I like this approach, though perhaps without the interaction terms.  I don't think causal inference methods need to be brought in unless there is some kind of after-randomization bias.